# Repeat process with previous input

Tags: python

In the below code, if the input is even, the number doubles, if not 1 is added. This goes on until the number is greater than 100.

```
number=int(input("Enter a number: "))
print(number)
while number < 100:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        number *= 2
    else:
        number = number+1
    print(number)
```

Once it has reached 100, I want it to repeat the same process for input+1. I can't use number=number+1 because it would use the last version of number rather than the original input.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Why not hang onto the original return value of `input()`? Hold this value unchanged and work on the existing `number` variable for your manipulations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two `loops` with to copies of `number`, for instance:

```
number=int(input("Enter a number: "))
print(number)
while number < 100:
    num = number
    while num < 100:    
        if num % 2 == 0:
            num *= 2
        else:
            num += 1
        print(num)
    number += 1
```